# 'signUpComponent' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: reactjs

I want to import the following components from the app component.

I don't know if the following reason appears.
: 'signUp Component' is declared but its value is not read

Also, clicking the button doesn't work. How can I solve it?

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';
import signUpComponent from './SignUpComponent';

function App() {
  
  const [signUpState, setSignUpState] = useState(false);
  
  function controllSignUp(){
      setSignUpState(!signUpState)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className ="SignIn">
            <h1>LOGIN</h1>
            <form className = "loginForm">
                <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                    <input
                      id="email"
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      placeholder="test@email.com"
                    />
                <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
                    <input
                      id="password"
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      placeholder="****************"
                    />
                <button type="submit">login</button>
              </form>
            <button onClick={controllSignUp}>signin</button>
            {signUpState && <signUpComponent/>}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your component name should start with a capital letter ...

Comment: As an aside, `signUpState` is a poor variable name. Consider `displaySignUpComponent` or `signUpEnabled` or something else that describes the context of the boolean and what its state tells you. Also, the "signin" button toggled the SignUpComponent, probably a typo?

Answer (score 1):

[User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Instead of

```
import signUpComponent from './SignUpComponent';
```

you need to do

```
import SignUpComponent from './SignUpComponent';
```